# What does a company mean when they say, "does not offer benefits"?

Tags: united-states, job-description, benefits

I came across a job posting that states,

> This is a full-time, salaried position. [Company] does not offer
>   benefits.

Does this mean they do not offer health/vision/dental insurance, PTO, 401k matching, among other benefits? Is this impossible to know without contacting the company?

Comment: There is no concrete description for benefits it can mean anything. Especially if the   posting is from recruiting agency

Comment: Early stage companies may not offer any kind of benefits beyond salary and options.

Comment: If it's a massage parlour that doesn't do extras then you just get a massage I think

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exactly what "benefits" means depends, and if you have any thought of working there I'd check with the company first.  They probably don't offer any sort of insurance, but they might have PTO or other time off.  I'd bet against 401(k) matching.

Comment: I'd bet against 401(k)s at all.

Comment: Presumbly, the first thing you should get clear is if they're hiring you as a fixed price contractor. In which case, not only will they offer nothing other than salary, you'll have to deal with the tax implications as well.